# Turning off display if webpage is not available in kiosk mode

Tags: display, raspberry-pi-os, kiosk

Am I using the pi in kiosk mode to monitor my pc stats. But I cant connect the pi the pc due to insufficient power to power the display as well. So I want the pi to rurn off the display if and only if the webpage is not avalaible. And in background check every 5 minutes or so if the page comes back online. ANd if the page is found only then it should turn the display back on.

Any ideas to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can the display be powered on? ... you said that there is not enough power to run the display, so just disconnect it